# Как узнать id родителя?

Tags: javascript

Как можно узнать id родителя в таблице? К примеру, есть таблица

```
<table>
    <tr id='id_tr'>
        <td id='id_td>Любой объект</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

Вот при нажатии на любой объект в `td`, я хочу узнать не только ид `td`, который равен '`id_td`', но еще хочу узнать ид родителя, т.е. ид строки '`id_tr`'. Как можно узнать на стороне js?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`element.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.parentNode)

Comment: А как узнать сам id строки?
$(this).parentElement.id ?
Когда смотрю в дебаге, то есть id  у строки, а когда пишу в скрипте, то на событие клик он пишет, что не знает id:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

как можно узнать, что бы не выдавал ошибки?

Comment: я вчера поправился, `parentElement` - IE-specific, юзайте стандартный `parentNode`